# Spring Boot - TestRestTemplate LocalDate of body null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, integration-testing, resttemplate

When I hit the service externally, both fields of type LocalDate are resolved okey, and the service works.

But when I try to test the very same endpoint using a TestRestTemplate the fields arrive to the controller as null. 
What's the problem?

UPDATE:
The problem is even worst. When I tried to test another service I found the deserialization done by the TestRestTemplate made a list of LocalDate to be build as an empty list.
I experiment with custom serializer and deserializer and nothing works. =/

Controller

```
@RestController
public class ReservationController {


@PostMapping("/reservation")
public String makeReservation(@RequestBody Reservation Reservation) {
    return this.reservationService.makeReservation(Reservation);
}
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppRunner.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ReservationControllerTest {

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

private TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();


@Test
public void attemp4(){
    LocalDate from = LocalDate.of(2019,1, 1);
    LocalDate to = LocalDate.of(2019,1, 21);

    Reservation Reservation = new Reservation(from, to);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Reservation> entity = new HttpEntity<>(Reservation, headers);

    String uri = "http://localhost:"+port+"/reservation";
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, entity, String.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(response);
}

}
```

Reservation / API DTO

```
public class Reservation {

private LocalDate checkIn;
private LocalDate checkOut;

public Reservation(LocalDate checkin, LocalDate checkout) {
    this.checkIn = checkin;
    this.checkOut = checkout;
}


public LocalDate getCheckIn() {
    return checkIn;
}

public LocalDate getCheckOut() {
    return checkOut;
}

}
```

Just in case, pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mysystem</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-2-jdbc-with-h2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <findbugs-maven-plugin.version>3.0.4</findbugs-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-source</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                                    <source>src/test/java</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-resource</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <runOrder>random</runOrder>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
</profiles>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure, but Reservation.class might need to implement Serializable-Interface.

Comment: @flomo83 Does not work. I even removed the only constructor that I had and  I added all the setters and getters (I was keeping the class inmutable) and did not work. Even worst, doing that all the fields are null then they arrived at the controller. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: avoid Instantiation by hand -> From [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html): If you are using the @ SpringBootTest annotation, a TestRestTemplate is automatically available and can be @ Autowired into your test. [...]

Comment: @flomo83 That solved the problem!!!! Thank you very much!